# Is there a spell that could be used to generate an EMP effect on a target?

Tags: spells, shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

I'm looking to create a spell-caster that would be efficient and annoying to technological targets, such as people with cyber augmentations, and I thought about giving him my character at least one spell that would generate an EMP effect.

Does such a spell exist? If not, is there anything that could be used to generate something similar?

I was thinking of using electricity-based spells if no EMP spells exists, would that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Interference (Street Grimoire, p. 117)

This allows you to jam devices in a certain area (provided that you can beat the object resistance roll):

Street grimoire, p. 105

> Interference creates a barrage of static in the electromagnetic
> spectrum jamming radio and wireless signals. This spell jams all signals in the area of effect with a Signal rating less than the hits scored by the spellcaster, just like a jammer (p. 248, SR5).

Doesn't permanently disable the devices, but has an effect most similar to what you're looking for.

#### Anything dealing Water damage

Not exactly what you're looking for but: It's an obvious attack, that doesn't do much but knock down the target. It has an additional effect on **unsealed devices** though that is more permanent than the spell above:

> Also, any exposed and unsealed electronics may be damaged. For any such devices, make a Device Rating (3) Test; failure means water hit the sensitive innards of the device and bricked it (see Bricking, p. 228, SR5).

You could give a spirit with an optional power an elemental attack for this or "waste" an [elemental] spell on this...

**Note on electricity spells**

You may use spells dealing electricity damage to the target device, which also deal matrix damage (see elemental effect in the core rules). You'll most likely destroy the device before bricking it though...

Comment: I play 4th edition way more than SR5, but in 4th at least there are also Wall spells (e.g. 'Wall of [element]', in Street Magic, but also shape [material]) that would potentially create problematic interference for devices with a low signal rating.  If that's still a thing in 5th it may bear mention.

Answer (score 5):

### Nope, because EMPs don't work.

The vast majority of Shadowrun technologies use optical circuitry and optical chips, especially the expensive ones like implants and cyberdecks. They are not subject to EMP. Even then, [popular culture references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse_in_popular_culture) do not actually depict what [EMPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse) actually are nor what they actually do.

In fact, if you do a deep dive into some of the setting background (particularly mana spikes and the ambient mana field level), things like EMPs and even nuclear weapons have not worked reliably since the Awakening in 2012. The how and why is a still a bit of a mystery to the denizens of the Sixth World, but the reality is unquestionable.

### Alternatives

There are spells like *Interference* (Street Grimoire, p. 105) that can create problems for augmented characters:

> Interference creates a barrage of static in the electromagnetic spectrum jamming radio and wireless signals. This spell jams all signals in the area of effect with a Signal rating less than the hits scored by the spellcaster, just like a jammer (p. 248, SR5).

However, the "problems" come in potentially denying the user access to any of their equipment's wireless-access-based bonuses. You're not going to be able to deprive a cyber-enhanced character of their implants completely. Of course, any reasonably intelligent character is going to have all their implants connected to a more powerful master device, like their commlink, and should be running software to deal with a jammer.

### Regarding Your Goal

One of Shadowrun's core setting design tropes - the rules of the story world - is that magic doesn't combine well with technology. You're not going to find a lot of support for the character you're trying to create, because that kind of character isn't supposed to exist in the setting. Sure, magicians can make physical phenomena (*Interference* creates static, an environmental phenomena with a side effect of "mucking with electronics", *Fireball* makes well... fire), but spells like *Fireball* only works against technology because everything burns if you get it hot enough.