# Shadowrun SR5: Can Lasers or Sunbeam Spells Damage Electronics?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, cyberware, lasers

Someone once said

> "The vast majority of Shadowrun technologies use optical circuitry and
> optical chips, especially the expensive ones like implants and
> cyberdecks"

So my question then is, can Optical Circuitry and Optical Chips, especially the really expensive ones, be damaged in an EMP like fashion with optical attacks? Would the frequency or band of frequencies be able to overload or wash out the optical chips?

I tripped over this statement:

> "My ISP said they have a main single glass strand which is the
> backbone. they have 1200 connections with each connection of 4mbps
> packages. According to them the backbone is overloaded"

about fiber optics and it does appear that you would either melt the optical sensors or quite possibly overload by way of amplitude a specific set of optical frequencies.

> "A common mistake that happens when using optical transceivers is that
> users tend to accidentally burn them out by overpowering the input
> side of the module. In other words, the module gets damaged from the
> overabundance of incoming light signals."

Likewise, is there any kind of reflective coating that can be applied to decker equipment, cyberlimbs, or armor, that is highly reflective and provides protection vs. optical attacks (like lasers?) Rifts had something like this for the Glitter Boy. Im curious if there's an armor mod that might do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a source for that assertion about Shadowrun using optical chips? That would help find any relevant rules text. Or are you asking for homebrew advice?

Comment: @MJD - Appears to come from [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/158919/3958) and that question is strongly related if this is not answered by that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a spell that could be used to generate an EMP effect on a target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158887/is-there-a-spell-that-could-be-used-to-generate-an-emp-effect-on-a-target)

Comment: To what extent is a real-life answer of “an EMP does/does not work on optical circuits” useful here? It is that even the desired answer—in which case this Stack might not be the right place for this question?